# AngularJS - Set active tabset after delete some one

Tags: angularjs, closures, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-tabset

I have a code that contains a button with a ng-click that when is pressed It add a new tab to the tabs array.

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()">Add</div>

$scope.add = function()
  {
     $scope.tabs.push({heading: 'new', content: 'ddddddd'});

     $timeout(function ()
    {
        $scope.active = $scope.tabs.length;
    });
  }
```

Then, the array is populated and showd in the view:

```
 <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" index="$index + 1">
      <uib-tab-heading>{{ tab.heading }} - <a ng-click="remove($index)">remove</a></uib-tab-heading>
        {{tab.content}}
      </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```

Also, each tab have a remove link that calls this function:

```
  $scope.remove = function(index)
  {
    $scope.tabs.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.active = $scope.tabs.length;
  }
```

The problem is that when I delete some tab that is not the last added tab, the active tab and index are not the same. There is a plunkr to demonstrate the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/02Lll7oPYyvAxcKu5GkK?p=preview As you can see, when a tab (no the last) is deleted, "Tabs" and "Index" variables are not the same.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Which tab you want to set active when any deleted?

Comment: When I delete a tab I not want to set a new active tab, simply mantain the last active tab. The problem comes when after delete a tab I add a new tab. In this moment yes, I want to set active this new tab, but I not get results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Currently the angular bootstrap doesn't support generating tab dynamically.
>   But if you want [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) solution worked.**
>   you can read more from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/611)

You need to define one function for `timeout` which will take care to make tab selected whenever you going to add new tab or remove any existing one.
Its take id of the tab which is last one in the tab list.

```
function callTimeOut(tabNoIndex) {

        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.active = tabNoIndex;
        }, 0);
      }
```

Your tab array should look like this one with `tabNo` as closure property.
This will track no of tab created till now as **`uitab` does not re-arranged the tab id once it is removed or added**.You have to take care of this one.

```
$scope.tabs.push({
          heading: 'new',
          content: 'ddddddd',
          id: ++tabNo
        });
```

Your add and remove function should look like this one.

```
$scope.add = function() {
        $scope.tabs.push({
          heading: 'new',
          content: 'ddddddd',
          id: ++tabNo
        });

        callTimeOut($scope.tabs.length);

      }


      $scope.remove = function(index) {
        $scope.tabs.splice(index, 1);

        var tabIndex = $scope.tabs[$scope.tabs.length - 1].id;
        callTimeOut(tabIndex);
      }
```

here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FlNphJEjExU0zPRNLSYV?p=preview)

Comment: Your Plunker is not functioning properly.
Notice that when you remove a tab that is not the last tab and then add a new one, index becomes null and no tab is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I stumbled upon it so other might too.

I solved it by deep cloning the array containing my tabs.

So here it would be :

```
$scope.remove = function(index) {
    $scope.tabs.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.tabs = angular.copy($scope.tabs);
    $timeout(function() {
        // need timeout, so that tab already exists when we set it active
        $scope.active = $scope.tabs.length;
    });
}
```